# ASP MVC IEnumerable<Image> model - validation for creating a new Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, ienumerable

i have a MVC application where i show a list of images.
My model is:

`@model IEnumerable<ImageGallery.Models.Image>`

On the same viewpage i have a form for adding a new image to the list.

```
<input asp-for="Name" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

This does not work, because "Name" is a field in the Image-class, but the model for this view is an IEnumerable and i can't reference to the "Name"-field. How is this solved?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another model/viewmodel to capture the data required to add a new image. I usually have a parent view model with the List and AddNew view model held together at the same level.

```
public class AddImageViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class MyImagesViewModel
{
    public IList<Image> MyImages {get;set;}

    public AddImageViewModel AddImage {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I can add new images (by just having a <form asp-action="Create">. The problem is i want to have validation on the fields. I am new to ASP MVC - how would i make that viewmodel? So i still have a list of my images, but the fields of the Image class to reference to for validation

Comment: I have updated my answer. Adding a new image and listing existing images are different things and therefore require different models